# Tracking wrist position using accelerometer in a smart watch

Tags: algorithm, embedded, signal-processing, iot, accelerometer

I am working on a smartwatch project. I want the display to be turned off and only come on when the user brings his hand into the watch-viewing position.
I am running my application on the NRF52 MCU which means machine learning is out of the question. I am using a 3-axis accelerometer from STM.
How can I detect when a user moves his hand into the typically watch viewing position? How is this achieved in smartwatches?

I have the following ideas so far:
- Constantly poll accelerometer and calculate pitch and roll values. Then determine what range of pitch and roll values corresponds to this gesture. This seems a bit wasteful because the CPU will have to be always active.

Is there a simple signal processing algorithm or something similar that can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Look into **Galvanic skin response sensor** - It can measure electrical connectivity of the skin.

When internal or external forces cause arousal — of any kind — the skin becomes a better conductor of electricity. Essentially, when you start to sweat, either from exercise or something else, the band will be able to monitor that.

Detecting when someone is sweating gives the software more information about what a user is doing, which allows for better health tracking. Being able to correlate the level of activity with a different source than just gravity from the accelerometer, allows these programs to take on a more trainer-like role — recommending specific exercises and levels of exertion.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment. I am interested in detecting when the hand is in the upright time-viewing position. I am not monitoring the health signals for now.